# I want form controls to wrap if they don't fit completely

Tags: css, forms, controls, padding

I want to make it so that if a control does not fit completely, it will automatically start on the next line.

A container I have looked like:

`http://i.imgur.com/N6UAMhr.png` (wrong)

I would like to use CSS padding to make it look like:

`http://i.imgur.com/PssWDpP.png` (right)

automatically as the page is resized. What is the proper way of doing this?

The code for this container is currently:

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/y9ha8dk4)

Apologies for the links. I can't embed images yet. And I can only post 2 links. And it actually tries to render my HTML. How frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely the `margin` property messing the styles for you.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pekU/2/)